# Make myOwnTriangle function with point

Tags: function, processing, trigonometry, point

I am writing my own function for drawing a triangle using only point() with the programming language "Processing".
This is my code:

```java
void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);
  background(#99c2ff);
  noLoop();
}

void myOwnTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3)
{
  int x=x1;
  int differenceY=abs(y1-y2); //y1=380; y2=50; (380-50)=330
  int differenceX=abs(x2-x1); //x2=300; x1=30; (300-30)=270
  int smallStep = differenceY/differenceX;// 330-270=60
  int stepcount=0;
  if (x1<=x2)
    for (int i=x1; i<=x2; i++)
    {
      for (int j=y2; j<=y1; j++)
        point(i, j);
        println("test1");
      stepcount++;

     }


    } 
}

void draw()
{
  stroke(#ff3399); 
  myOwnTriangle(30, 380, 300, 50, 380, 250);
}
```

Until `println("test1");` I have checked and the program works, then I don't understand why it won't draw the point with `if (smallStep%stepcount==0);`
the expected behavior should be the first triangle's line(of point).
Can someone help me to complete this function?

thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. That `if` statement doesn't have a body, so it isn't going to run any code.

Comment: @KevinWorkman You are right. But even if I delete 'if (smallStep%stepcount==0);' the function should draw an oblique line. The 'println("test1");'  works, so I don't understand why point(); it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own **solution** at the end:

```java
void setup()
{
  size(400, 400);
  background(#99c2ff);
  noLoop();
}

void myOwnTriangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3)
{
  myLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  myLine( x2, y2, x3, y3);
  myLine( x3, y3, x1, y1);
}

void myLine(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2) 
{
  float dx = x2-x1;
  float dy = y2-y1;
  if (dx == 0) {
    for (float i = min(y1, y2); i<max(y1, y2); i+=1) 
    {
      point(x1, i);
    }
    return;
  }
  float k = dy/dx;
  float m = y1 -x1*k;
  for (float i = min(x1, x2); i<max(x1, x2); i+=1/max(1, abs(k))) {
    point(i, k*i+m);
  }
}

void draw()
{
  noLoop();
  strokeWeight(2);
  stroke(2, 0, 255);
  myOwnTriangle(80, 50, 215, 300, 215, 100);
  stroke(#ff00ff);
  myOwnTriangle(80, 80, 80, 300, 215, 100);
  stroke(#00ff00);
  myOwnTriangle(100, 250, 300, 250, 200, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most important skill you need to learn is [how to debug](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your program.

You've added a `println("test1");` line, and that's a great start. But you need to go a step further and print out the values of every variable, that way you can better understand what your code is doing.

First off, notice that your `for` loop does not end in a `{` curly bracket:

```
for (int j=y1; j<=y2; j++)
    point(i, j);
    println("test1");
```

This means that only the `point(i, j);` line is "inside" the `for` loop, and your `println()` statement is outside that loop! You can fix that by adding `{ }` curly brackets:

```
for (int j=y1; j<=y2; j++){
    println(i + ", " + j);
    point(i, j);
    println("test1");
}
```

Also notice that I've added another `println()` statement to figure out what the values of `i` and `j` are inside this loop. But if your run this program, you'll find out that this loop never runs!

To figure out why that's happening, you can add more `println()` statements just before the inner loop:

```
for (int i=x1; i<=x2; i++){
  println("i: " + i);
  println("y1: " + y1);
  println("y2: " + y2);
  for (int j=y1; j<=y2; j++){
    println(i + ", " + j);
    point(i, j);
    println("test1");
  }
}
```

If you run this, you'll see that `y1` is `380` and `y2` is `50`. So then your loop sets `j` equal to `y1` (which is `300`) and then checks whether it's less than `y2` (which is `50`). That is never true (`380` is never less than `50`), so your loop doesn't run. That's why you aren't seeing any points being drawn.

You're going to have to take a step back and figure out exactly what you want to do in this case. But more importantly, you need to get into the habit of debugging your code to understand exactly what it's doing.

Comment: thank you a lot, I have understood quite well your explanations and your instructions, It's true I am not really aware concerning how I should "debug", thank you for the link I will read it. I fixed the code and I have tried even with '((x1<=x2)&(y2<=y1))' and '((x1<=x2)||(y2<=y1))' but actually everything from the second 'for' it's not working, I can see the 'y2' that is not increased and there isn't anymore 'test1'. Is it because I should write first a code that draw all the triangle's lines/sides or because there is something else? like it's wrong the main concept of my code?

Comment: @MirielLind Think about exactly what your `for` loop is checking against. What happens if you feed it numbers in reverse order? That's what you're doing. If you want to draw a line from x position of `500` to `100`, what do you want to happen?